# XPath ancestor-or-self resolution order

Tags: xml, xpath

So I'm trying to use XPath (1.0) to get all elements of a certain type for which either itself or any ancestor has a specific parameter value. The trick is that the parameter can be a list of values, so I can't just look for @parameter='value'. This is an example of a document for my case, and let's say I'm looking for xref elements for which either them or any of their ancestors have platform="mobile":

```
<doc>
    <block>
        <xref platform="mobile desktop">1</xref>
    </block> 
    <block platform="mobile">
        <xref platform="desktop">2</xref>
    </block>
    <block platform="desktop">
        <xref platform="mobile">3</xref>
    </block>
</doc>
```

I (with some help) came up with the following XPath that seems to almost make it:

```
//xref[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(ancestor-or-self::*/@platform), ' '), ' mobile ')]
```

The goal was for the concat to concatenate all values of platform for xref's ancestors and itself at the same time, and then see if mobile was in there. So in the example document it should return all 3 xrefs, but it doesn't, it omits the 3rd one. I think the ancestor-or-self evaluates from root level down, so once it finds a platform that is not mobile it fails, without actually checking the rest of the ancestors or the self. Plus with this behavior concat isn't really doing anything, as it is just looking at the platform value of one node at once.

Does anyone know how to solve this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, string function like `normalize-space()` which expects a string parameter, when given a node-set, will only evaluates the first node in the set. So the following expression would evaluate only the first found `platform` attribute :

```
normalize-space(ancestor-or-self::*/@platform)
```

To avoid the problem mentioned, OP's attempted XPath can be tweaked a bit to be as follow :

```
//xref[
    ancestor-or-self::*[
        contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@platform), ' '), ' mobile ')
    ]
]
```

**demo :** [`xpathtester`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/6151eee0440b67a042cf4d820272a742), [`xpatheval`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/ENS1Ceb0x)

This way the string functions are applied on `platform` attribute of individual `ancestor-or-self` elements.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I knew I had tried something similar at one point so I looked through my attempts, and found one just like this but with a / after the * so it didn't work. To be honest I don't have the understanding to know why that / shouldn't be there, but thanks!

Comment: @AndresMata You are welcome! I'd think of it as: predicate (`[...]`) needs a context node to be applied on, and the context is the node to the left. So `/[...]` is never correct syntax since there is nothing to the left of the predicate except a path separator, Contrast with `/ancestor-or-self::*[...]` where elements selected by `ancestor-or-self::*` would be the context of the predicate

Answer (score 1):

The xpath below

```
//xref[contains( @platform, 'mobile' )] | //xref/ancestor::*[contains( @platform, 'mobile' )]/xref
```

gives me :

```
<xref platform="mobile desktop">1</xref>
<xref platform="desktop">2</xref>
<xref platform="mobile">3</xref>
```

Comment: Well this may be because I wasn't very clear on my question, but I see a couple of issues with this xpath... it might be possible for another platform value to be "fakemobile", so just to ask if it contains the "mobile" substring isn't enough, it might be part of a different platform value. The other issue is that it's not always the direct ancestor of the xref that has the value, it could be any ancestor... But thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're probably using XPath 1.0 (you really should say), because otherwise `normalize-space(ancestor-or-self::*/@platform)` would give an error when there is more than one attribute selected.

In XPath 1.0 this expression will apply normalize-space to the first node in the node-set in document order, which means the outermost @platform, since ancestors precede their descendants in document order. If you want the innermost @platform, use `normalize-space((ancestor-or-self::*/@platform)[last()])`.

But if you're selecting elements where any ancestor has an @platform containing "mobile" as a substring, that would be

```
//xref[ancestor::*/@platform[contains(., 'mobile')]]
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm just learning XPath so I wasn't aware of the version differences. I'm using the javax.xml.xpath library in Java 8, and according to documentation it complies with XPath 1.0. Is there an easy way of expanding this answer to instead of mobile being a substring of platform for it to match one of the values given in the list? For example, if it can match platform="desktop mobile" but not platform="desktop mobileBrowser". I have a couple of cases like that.

Comment: If you're using Java then there's no reason to be restricted to XPath 1.0: there are several products implementing XPath 2.0 or 3.0, or XQuery, which are far more powerful: my own Saxon product is one of them. However, you can do the match in 1.0 by the trick you were already using: change the predicate to `[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(.), ' '), ' mobile ')].